# Best way to check if external data is already in our MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

We are looking at the best way of developing a search routine in a database that uses the least resources possible within a PHP/MySQL environment.

We process an external feed of information that has a tendency to subtly change or have new status values from time to time. This means we are limited to add our own numeric keys and search by conventional SQL search.

We are thinking of using MD5 to create a unique string so instead of searching for...

```
WHERE DATE = '12/12/2012 09:00' 
AND TYPE = 'new alert' 
AND loc = 'rear door' 
AND subtype = 'pir hit' 
AND lat = 39.3343 
AND lon = 145.234 
AND current STATUS = 'active' 
AND Support = 'en-route';
```

we create a MD5 e.g. ef6d3c25ac9362413fed2b4d3f65962a out of the fields that we are interested in e.g.
12/12/2012 09:00~new alert~rear door~pir hit~-39.3343~145.234~active~en-route and then we can search for just this MD5 in the database rather than separate fields.

We would also be interested in looking into using a file with the list of most recent MD5's rather that interrogating the db constantly as we may have 1100+ jobs in the feed at the most. More often it is around 60 or so jobs.

We are interested in your thoughts and reasons on what you think is the best solution.

Comment: Wow!  DO NOT encrypt normal cells in your database with MD5. You won't be able to read the data in the future!

Comment: @aguyfromhere: The OP is proposing an additional search index field with a hash, presumably. They don't need to reverse the hash, which of course isn't reasonable.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Seems ridiculous to use a huge hash when something like `PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT` could work just fine.

Comment: @aguyfromhere: How would that aid searchability, in the way the OP is looking for?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: If they do it by hash then they need every single piece of information that makes up the hash, and if it's off by even one white space it won't find any results. Sounds like an awful way to manage a database to me.  Sorry.

Comment: That's how search works, sometimes. Everything must match, or the search result is no good. Doesn't sound that terrible to me, though there are better non-bespoke solutions. Kapo mentions one.

Comment: Thanks aguyfromhere and Michael. We normalize the database and all our internal keys are numeric however we retrieve data from 10+ organisations and these feeds can change and do change without notice. We need the process to run even if we don't fully understand the new status codes etc. We also do a fair bit of tidying up where we can so double spaces and the like are normally excluded. Most of these status fields are database generated at the source so we can normally rely on the data not changing for an event. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for Apache Solr as a solution. Faceted search would suite all your needs here. Replicating/indexing your data wouldn't take much effort. We've implemented this engine in our company's project, doing search over name/date/characteristics/vendor/distributor/etc, and it works like a charm. Though md5 over glued string has been a solution for some time there. Anyways, it depends on time you have and how well your current solution handles the situation.

Comment: Thanks to Michael Petrotta and Kapo. We have a while to implement the new process so we can afford time to look at Apache Solr and other solutions.